# Sql Server: Partition Dataset While Preserving Row Groupings

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning

I have a query that returns rows grouped according to two columns, like this:

```
Student_ID  Module_ID  Assignment_date  Assignment_grade
1           2          2010-01-01       C
1           2          2012-02-02       E
1           2          2013-03-02       A*
3           6          2013-03-02       B
3           6          2013-03-02       B
```

I am trying to improve performance by processing the result set in parallel. To do this, I need to partition the result set into sections of close-to-equal size whilst ensuring row groupings are not spread across more than one partition because the groupings are important for processing. **This has to be done using multiple queries**, rather than one query and then partitioning the results because partitioning the rows after querying the data incurs too much of an overhead (the intention is to assign each query to a `SqlDataReader`).

Normally, I would use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign numbers to rows and then add a WHERE clause to each query similar to `WHERE row_number > lowerbound AND row_number < upperbound` but this could result in the dataset being split in the middle of a grouping.

How can I ensure each query I use selects a different section of the data and each grouping within the result contains all rows in the grouping?

I thought of using `DENSE_RANK()` to assign an ID to each grouping, but I can't figure out how to utilise this in conjuction with row numbers to achieve my desired results.

The ideal result in this example would be one query that returns this:

```
Student_ID  Module_ID  Assignment_date  Assignment_grade
1           2          2010-01-01       C
1           2          2012-02-02       E
1           2          2013-03-02       A*
```

And another query that returns this:

```
Student_ID  Module_ID  Assignment_date  Assignment_grade
3           6          2013-03-02       B
3           6          2013-03-02       B
```

Comment: Are you accessing thie data in C# then you could query all the data and use `.ToLookup(x => x.Student_Id)` in your C# code to create partitions based on studentId

Comment: What is a row grouping?

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts yep through C#, unfortunately performance testing has shown that querying all the data, partitioning it, and then doing processing (even just querying all data and then processing without partitioning) is slower than loading and processing rows 1-by-1 using a DataReader.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You know what I mean! GROUP BY causing rows to be grouped together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to identify groups of students, you can use either `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
select t.*, rank() over (order by student_id) as number_r
from t;
```

or:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by student_id) as number_dr
from t;
```

What is the difference between the two?  `RANK()` produces counts that correspond to the first row number of each group.  `DENSE_RANK()` just counts by groups.

So, `where number_r <= 3` will fetch all groups up to and including the group that has the third row.  In your case, this would be the first three rows.

But `where number_dr <= 3` will fetch the first three groups.  In your case, it would select all rows -- and even the next group is not in the data example.

Comment: this was just what the doctor ordered

Answer (score 0):

You can use WINDOWS function as follows:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT T.*, 
                    COUNT(1) OVER () AS CNT, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY STUDENT_ID, MODULE_ID, ASSIGNMENT_DATE) AS RN,
                    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY STUDENT_ID, MODULE_ID) AS DR
               FROM YOUR_TABLE T)
SELECT T1.*
  FROM CTE T 
-- WHERE DR <= (SELECT MAX(DR) FROM CTE T2 WHERE RN <= CEIL(CNT/2)) -- FIRST PART
-- WHERE DR >= (SELECT MIN(DR) FROM CTE T2 WHERE RN > CEIL(CNT/2)) -- SECOND PART
```